# Get line of a specific tag in xml

Tags: javascript, xml, xmldom

I am making an XML document and a JavaScript parse function to parse the XML document the way i want to.

In my XML document there is a <note> Tag and i want my parser function to get all the Notes and push Each Note value into an Array (that i can do on my own). But, The problem is that i want that each time i push inside the for loop a value into the Array i push it like that:

```js
Array.push(Node.childNodes[0].data + " | Line: " + Node.line/*Or something like that*/)
```

How could i get the line of the Specific Note Element the function is parsing right now?

Comment: That's somewhat confusing, the XML parser probably has no concept of linenumbers, and `childNodes`  etc. just gets the nodes, regardless of whitespace and newlines in your file. You'll probably have to get the content of the file as just plain text and count the number of newlines ?